# Appending BSTR in a LPCSTR

Tags: c++, string-concatenation, bstr, lpcstr

I have a class function which is receving a BSTR. In my class I have a member variable which is LPCSTR. Now I need to append BSTR ins LPCSTR. How I can do that.
Here is my function.

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(BSTR text)
{
    LPCSTR name = "Name: ";
    m_classMember = name + text; // m_classMember is LPCSTR.
}
```

in my m_classMember I want that after this function value should be "Name: text_received_in_function". How i can do that.

Comment: this is member of class, it is LPCSTR, what should i use here,

Comment: it is not pointing to anything,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Microsoft specific [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class, which handles the ANSI/Unicode natively. Something like

```
#include <comutils.h>
// ...

void MyClass::MyFunction(BSTR text)
{
    _bstr_t name = "Name: " + _bstr_t(text, true);
    m_classMember = (LPCSTR)name;
}
```

is what you almost want. However, as pointed out by the remarks, you have to manage the lifetime of `m_classMember` and the concatened string. In the example above, the code is likely to crash.

If you own the `MyClass` object, you could simply add another member variable:

```
class MyClass {
private:
  _bstr_t m_concatened;
//...
};
```

and then use `m_classMember` as a pointer to the string content of `m_concatened`.

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(BSTR text)
{
    m_concatened = "Name: " + _bstr_t(text, true);
    m_classMember = (LPCSTR)m_concatened;
}
```

Otherwise, prior to the assignment of `m_classMember`, you should free it in the same way you allocated it (`free`, `delete []`, etc), and create a new `char*` array in which you copy the content of the concatened string. Something like

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(BSTR text)
{
    _bstr_t name = "Name: " + _bstr_t(text, true);

    // in case it was previously allocated with 'new'
    // should be initialized to 0 in the constructor
    delete [] m_classMember; 
    m_classMember = new char[name.length() + 1];

    strcpy_s(m_classMember, name.length(), (LPCSTR)name);
    m_classMember[name.length()] = 0;
}
```

should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you to *not* use raw `char/wchar_t*` pointers as data members for strings; in general, it's better (easier, more maintainable, exception-safe, etc.) to use a robust C++ **string class**.

Since you are writing Windows code, you may want to use `ATL::CString`, which is well integrated in the context of Win32 programming (e.g.: it offers several conveniences, like loading strings from resources, it works out-of-the-box with the `TCHAR` model, etc.).

If you want to work with the `TCHAR` model (and make your code compilable in both ANSI/MBCS and Unicode builds), you may want to use the [ATL string conversion helper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `CW2T` to convert from `BSTR` (which is Unicode `wchar_t*`) to `char*` in ANSI/MBCS build, and leave it as `wchar_t*` in Unicode builds.

```
#include <atlstr.h>    // for CString
#include <atlconv.h>   // for CW2T

void MyClass::MyFunction(BSTR text)
{
    // Assume:
    // CString m_classMember;

    m_classMember = _T("Name: ");

    // Concatenate the content of the BSTR.
    // CW2T keeps the BSTR as Unicode in Unicode builds,
    // and converts to char* in ANSI/MBCS builds.
    m_classMember += CW2T(text);
}
```

Instead, if you just want to compile your code in Unicode (which makes sense in today's world), you can get rid of `_T("...")` decoration and `CW2T`, and just use:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(BSTR text)
{
    // Assume:
    // CString m_classMember;

    m_classMember = L"Name: ";

    // Concatenate the content of the BSTR.
    m_classMember += text;
}
```

(Or use STL's `std::wstring` as others suggested.)